# The conservation or renovation quandary

Tags: restoration

I have an early 90s Raleigh in below-average condition. The frame colours are a bit naff -- sort of sky blue meets white with black serif lettering.

It was bought cheap off eBay after sitting in a garage for decades. The bike is at the end of its natural life and needs most components replaced. My plan was to give it a new lease of life with an all over spray from [spray.bike](https://spray.bike) and new vinyl lettering, with a name of my choosing, new tyres, tubes, handlebar grips -- the works. I would keep only the red/gold Raleigh badge on the head tube.

However, my immediate neighbours -- cyclists in their 50s and 60s -- have a soft spot for Raleighs, particularly from this era, and seem to think conservation is better than renovation. This has given me pause, and made me wonder if I wouldn't be losing something by spraying over the bike.

---

- Is there a consensus that renovating a classic bike from a reputable company is fair play, or would I be breaking a tacit bicycle commandment by doing this?
- Has anyone regretted carrying out such an operation?

Comment: To moderators: I'm aware this is heavily opinion-based, but I urge you to keep it open, edit it if necessary, or make it community wiki. There is a legitimate and compelling question of conservation here, and I'm sure the answers will be enlightening for many.

Comment: Isn’t this mostly a matter of the bike’s condition, your budget and what you want to do with it? If the paint is in good condition, why repaint? If it’s in (somewhat) bad condition and you can afford it, why not repaint it? I think some older bikes have vintage value, but for me personally it’s just a tool to get from A to B.

Comment: What sort of bike? For a 90s Raleigh in particular, the consensus might be different for a road bike and a proto-MTB.  Whether or not you plan to restore the original drivetrain or bolt on a load of new components would also be a factor

Comment: @Michael That's what I want to ascertain. The 'why not' argument seems intuitive to me but then I wondered whether there is a greater responsibility toward keeping some historical provenance of the bike.

Comment: @ChrisH It's a Pioneer, a hybrid utility bike with 700 x 35c tyres, 6-speed. The drivetrain is fine -- I can get by with 6 speeds, so will just clean it up and install a new chain.

Comment: If the bike is rare or has some historical significance, then I'd certainly be in favor of restoration/preservation. Otherwise, no. By 1990, Raleigh was just a badge owned by another company. If your neighbors want to restore the bike, perhaps sell it to them and let them do it.

Comment: For a hybrid I'd say there's no point worrying, just do what makes it nicest for you

Comment: @AdamRice Thanks, this is just what I wanted to know. For future reference, what would you regard as rare or historically significant enough to preserve?
ChrisH - Thanks, no qualms about proceeding with this now.

Comment: I don’t consider that bike worthy of conservation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1 Is there a consensus that renovating a classic bike from a reputable company is fair play, or would I be breaking a tacit bicycle commandment by doing this?
>
> 2 Has anyone regretted carrying out such an operation?

**Question 1:**
There is no consensus on renovating vs. conserving

There are no global tacit bicycle commandments.
There are localized tastes and peer pressure. Localization may be just the group of people you know. Some attitudes may be city, county or country wide.
The role tacit bicycle commandments should play in determining what is best for you in your situation is questionable.

**Question 2:**
Yes, there are people who have regretted carrying out such an operation.
I have regretted both conservation and renovation.

There are also people who have enjoyed and have been happy with both operations.

Here's my story

*Renovation* - once it was all done, time and money spent, I rode the bike every day. The lovingly painted frame chipped up, the new parts dinged up, and common usage took it's toll.
My conclusion was that it's better to ride a dinged up bike than to renovate it to new and ding it up again. I began to see the wear and tear as a sign of a well used bike and not something to feel bad about.

*Conservation* - once it was all done, time and money spent, I had a bike I couldn't ride for fear it would get dirty or more dinged up. It became a museum piece. Now it collects dust in my basement.

Before you start on either project ask yourself "What will I do with this when I'm done"

Do what meets your needs and your aesthetic.

Comment: +1 Wish I could accept both answers. This more directly answers the questions asked so I will accept this.

Answer (score 3):

By way of background, [this Cyclingtips article](https://cyclingtips.com/2019/02/bikes-of-the-bunch-bianchi-specialissima-x-4/) lists three general approaches to approaching classic road bikes. NB: I'm not sure if the term restoration is mainly limited to restoring components, or if it is usually understood to include repainting.

> When it comes to rescuing a classic road bike, there are three schools of thought. The first is to treat is as an artefact. The second is to turn back time by reconditioning and restoring the bike to its former glory. And the third is to renovate and update it to suit the modern era.

> While there are good arguments for each approach, the divide that separates them is sometimes immense. There are times when devotees will go to war to defend their ideology, especially when it concerns a much loved and revered brand, like Bianchi. Indeed, one misstep can be viewed as a desecration.

The amount of heritage that the brand and perhaps a particular model has might sway you towards preservation. In road cycling, my primary discipline, heritage often arises through affiliation with a prominent team or rider. For example, when Eddy Merckx was racing with Molteni, the team's color was orange. When Merckx retired and launched his own line of bikes, many of them were in the same shade of orange as an homage, and I bet many owners of steel Merckxs would prefer to preserve the original scheme. Bianchi's signature color is celeste (a shade of green), so the color is inseparable from the brand even though some Bianchis have come in other main colors. Mapei, a very successful Classics team, had a distinctive paint scheme, and they raced on Colnagos, so I bet most people who bought a Colnago in a Mapei scheme would prefer to restore the bike to that scheme.

Another factor that might lend some objectivity towards a decision to restore to an original paint scheme and perhaps original parts is the frame's value at the time of sale. I think that if given an entry-level Bianchi from the 1980s, most observers would not insist on repainting it to the original scheme, or even to a classic Bianchi paint scheme. In the future, I'd speculate that the sport's degree of technical advancement might make people less likely to seek a restoration to older paint or components. I also suspect there may be cultural changes that affect a desire to preserve bicycles in their original configurations. You don't mention your age, but you did mention that your neighbors are in their 50s and 60s. You also don't mention your country, but I would speculate that the desire for preserving heritage bicycles is probably lower among younger cyclists in the US than among older US and European cyclists. I don't have knowledge about where younger European cyclists might fit in; in general, my impression is that Europeans may value tradition more than Americans, but that could be cultural stereotyping.

For the record, the Cyclingtips article discussed how one shop owner came into possession of a Bianchi Specialissima X-4, made from 1986 to 1992, and rode by Moreno Argentin and his team. I believe the paint scheme was standard Bianchi celeste, [as documented by Velo Aficionado](https://veloaficionado.com/blog/specialissima-bianchi-x-4-argentin).

[image]

The owner elected to paint the bike blue, as shown below. He actually received conflicting advice on restoring the original paint versus choosing a new paint scheme, but part of what swayed him was that he acquired the bike with paint in poor condition. He stated that if the bike had been in "pristine" condition, he would consider changing the paint scheme to be "sacrilege".

[image]

In a different article, [Matt Wikstrom of Cyclingtips](https://cyclingtips.com/2017/02/the-pros-and-cons-of-restoring-a-classic-road-bike/) documents the process of restoring an older frameset, in his case a Concorde Squadra. I don't believe he repainted the bike, even though there were paint chips and the clear coat had degraded. He did update it to modern components. Some people may prefer to source vintage components. However, finding ones of the correct period can be involved and pricey. Finding new old stock (NOS) versions can be even more so. In [yet another article](https://cyclingtips.com/2013/01/bikes-of-the-bunch-colnago-c35-oro/), an unnamed Cyclingtips writer documented a limited Colnago C35. It mentioned that paint restorers can take the approach of repainting an older frame entirely, or of doing more limited restorations to the finish (e.g. touch up chips).

---

### A digression on Bianchi "celeste"

In Italian, the word "celeste" may mean something more like pale or sky blue, [as documented here](http://www.boscarol.com/celeste.pdf). The word, after all, shares an etymology with "celestial", and celeste refers to the color of the heavens. There may be multiple origin stories for how Bianchi came across its signature color. Two are documented in [this Bicycling article](https://www.bicycling.com/news/a20014309/bianchi-celeste/). Thus, it's not 100% for certain that you or your painter would reproduce the 'correct' shade of Bianchi celeste for a specific year.

Moreover, the actual shade may have varied over the years. My understanding is that the color called British Racing Green (which originated in automotive racing, but which some bikes have received) may have the same problems, and it may be hard for painters to reproduce the exact shade. My understanding, from conversations with framebuilders, is that the type of primer used and the number of coats of paint applied can influence the final color.

Comment: +1 Very interesting - thanks for the great detail. I am in my early 30s and live in the UK. I probably fall squarely in the middle of preservation debate. I suppose I mentioned the age of my neighbours because the Raleigh name (to me) brings to mind a formerly glorious cycling past, of which they have direct experience.